# Trade convoy turn length

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I built 2 trade convoys from my capital city. I noticed when I tried to build a third, that my first convoy appeared to have ended, since that route was available again. Is there a turn number limit that a convoy lasts? If so, what can be done to increase that limit?

I checked through the Civlopedia, but I couldn't find anything that indicated a limit for trade convoys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trade routes, both land and sea, have a limited duration. At the end of this you keep the convoy/vessel and can assign it to another trade route (or to the same one).

If the convoy/vessel actually disappeared, it was probably destroyed by either an enemy or an alien.

Comment: This helped me figure out what was going on. I queued up some more trade convoys, but they hadn't been built. The convoys I was assigning were ones that had "completed" their trading while the new convoys were still being built. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The length of trade routes in turns in beyond earth is 10 turns on normal speed, instead of the 25 turns in Civ 5. The length can't be changed beyond the change associated with changing game speeds.

(You will probably grow to hate this because it makes micromanaging your traderoutes a pain)

Comment: I recently started up a new game after a fairly long break from the game and there is now a checkbox to have a route auto-renew that you can click on when assigning the convoy to a route. Definitely helps with the micromanaging.